# web services standards in SOA

Tags: service, standards

Web services are becoming heart of SOA. The term Web services describes a standardized way of integrating Web-based applications using the XML, SOAP, WSDL and UDDI open standards over an Internet protocol backbone. 
XML is used to tag the data, SOAP is used to transfer the data, WSDL is used for describing the services available and UDDI is used for listing what services are available.
can anyone tell that how the above are used in web services with a sample example (in java), for example how can we use xml in building of web services for SOA?

--ThankYou

Comment: This question is very vague and general. Please ask some questions that are more specific. The answer to your question would fill a book.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good book to read:

[http://www.amazon.com/Building-Web-Services-Java-Making/dp/0672326418](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672326418)

Answer (score 0):

Download a copy of [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org) and look at any of the samples.